# non-www URL goes to www-homepage instead of that particular page

Tags: url, apache, url-rewriting, no-www

Let's say my domain is `www.example.com`. if I type in `example.com` it goes to `www.example.com` - which is fine.

But the problem is if I type in `example.com/jamie/` it still goes to `www.example.com` -  the homepage of the website.

In order to go to the particular URL I have to type in with `www.example.com/jamie/` to land on that URL.

How do I make it go to a particular URL without type `www`?

My backend is on Django, Apache, AWS EC2.

Comment: Do you use an _.htaccess_ file to perform the redirect from `no-www` to `www`? If so, please share it.

Comment: Without a copy of the code in your .htaccess file, which I assume is the method of redirection, we cannot possibly even guess what the problem is or even begin to comment. If you are using a control panel of some sort to set up the redirection, then that would also be important information. Which one for example? Screen shots maybe? Cheers!!

Comment: I second that.  We would need to see your htaccess to make any conclusions as to what might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you are doing the redirection currently. But whatever it is, change it to the following in a virtual host with a `ServerName` of `example.com` (or in the default virtual host if using that as a catchall vhost).

```
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
```